# Simplest and robustest way to convert a Method of a static class into MethodInfo

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, static-methods, methodinfo

Is was wondering if there is no easier and robuster way to convert a static Method of a static class into a `MethodInfo` than writing

```
typeof(MyStaticClass).GetMethod("MyStaticMethod")
```

My aim is to write a `Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>` where i can map a `Type` to a Method.

```
MethodDictionary[typeof(bool)].Invoke(null, new object[] {});
```

I know that in C# 6 there is the possibility to write

```
typeof(MyStaticClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyStaticMethod))
```

But i'd like to stick to C# 5

Comment: See the response of @Ad P. in that page.

Comment: That does not work for static classes

Comment: *Console.WriteLine(NameOfHelper.nameof(() => string.Copy("")));* doesn't work? (fourth example)

Comment: ok youre right, i was wrong , `(NameOfHelper.nameof(() => MyStaticMethod(null))` works